# how to remove backslash from the value of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following type of arrays

- `["def, \" \""]`
- `["abc,\" \",def"]`

How can i check if there's a `\` in value and convert them correctly as follows?

- `["def", " "]`
- `["abc", " ", "def"]`

I have been trying to correct them using 
`join(',')` 
`delete('\"')` `split(', ')`
but no luck

Comment: There are no backslashes in your array. There is a single string `'def, " "'`.

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
input = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"num\": 3}"
```

The actual string stored in input is:

```
{ "foo": "bar", "num": 3}
```

The escape \" here is interpreted by Ruby parser, so that it can distinguish between the boundary of a string (the left most and the right most "), and a normal character " in a string (the escaped ones).

String#delete deletes a character set specified the first parameter, rather than a pattern. All characters that is in the first parameter will be removed. So by writing

```
input.delete('\\"')
```

You got a string with all \ and " removed from input, rather than a string with all \" sequence removed from input. This is wrong for your case. It may cause unexpected behavior some time later.

Comment: The backslash notation is pretty common across Perl, Python, C, C++, JavaScript...